# Function not immediately executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `showLoading()` that shows a spinner by appending a class:

```
function showLoading(){
    //console.log("show loading");
    loading = true;
    $("body").addClass("loading");
}
```

I call it like this:

```
Function heavyCrunch(){
    showLoading();

    <heavy crunching>

    hideLoading();
}
```

Now whenever I call the function just before some heavy load which takes > 1 second, it should show the spinner immediately, but it does not. In fact, it doesn't show at all. Whenever I click a button that triggers the `heavyCrunch()` function, it just freezes for a second or 2 and then immediately show the result. The spinner never shows. Why does this happen?

Should I call the function in an `.after` callback or something?

Comment: What sort of heavy crunching? Is it JavaScript processing?

Comment: Yes, it iterates trough a large array to compute a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DOM isn't refreshed while your code is executing. It waits until the end.

If you want the change to be visible, you have to defer the execution:

```
function heavyCrunch(){
    showLoading();
    setTimeout(function(){

        <heavy crunching>

        hideLoading();
    }, 0);
}
```

Note that in some cases of heavy processing you might want to release the pressure on the browser and let it the time to really draw. In such a case you may use a timeout greater than `0`.

Comment: little snippet for force redraw/refresh DOM `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: @SimoneNigro You still need to defer the execution

Answer (score 2):

Mandatory jQuery answer:

```
$.when(showLoading()).done(function () {
    heavyCrunch();
});
```

**Ref:** https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

**Example:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q67hwwa9/)